# About the accuracy of the time.Timer

Tags: go, timer

```
package main


import (
    "time"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    TestTicker(wg)
    wg.Wait()
}

func TestTicker(wg sync.WaitGroup) {
    calDuration := func(duration time.Duration) time.Duration {
        now := time.Now()
        return now.Truncate(duration).Add(duration).Sub(now)
    }
    go func(){
        t := time.NewTimer(calDuration(time.Minute))
        for {
            <-t.C
            fmt.Println(time.Now())
            t.Reset(calDuration(time.Minute))
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()
}
```

It sometimes happens to tick twice a minute as the duration may shrink. It's really strange. Could somebody help me. Thanks

I simply use waitgroup to hold the main function while calling TestTicker.

I'm running the test code on my MacOS

```
2018-07-19 14:36:00.003887996 +0800 CST m=+24.916092657
2018-07-19 14:37:00.002985076 +0800 CST m=+84.917119245
2018-07-19 14:38:00.001214551 +0800 CST m=+144.917278207
2018-07-19 14:39:00.000418561 +0800 CST m=+204.918411736
2018-07-19 14:39:59.999490194 +0800 CST m=+264.919412884
2018-07-19 14:40:00.000167519 +0800 CST m=+264.920090231
2018-07-19 14:40:59.99914446 +0800 CST m=+324.920996684
2018-07-19 14:41:00.000247228 +0800 CST m=+324.922099488
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I see you are using `wg.Done`. Are there any other goroutines?

Comment: Same here, I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @leafbebop Sorry for that. I just missed the main function. I attempt to integrate this in my project and I'm providing a test here and I doesn't work in a function. However, We can have a test. I turn out to be very accurate putting the code in the main function

Answer (score 1):

The timer accuracy can vary depending on your OS, hardware and CPU load. Virtual Machines  seem particularly bad at providing accurate timers (see https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14410). Unfortunately, you do not mention in what environment you're running this code.

If you can live with the inaccuracies, and still need your code do do something at about a full minute, your code breaks because when the interval is too short (`14:39:59.999490194` is only 500µs short of `14:40`), `calDuration` will make it wait that few microseconds until the next full minute. In order to fix this you need to use `Duration.Round` instead of `Duration.Truncate`.

Also do not forget that t.C returns the time at which the timer fired, so you need to use this value in your call to `calDuration` (this also saves you a costly syscalls).

```
func TestTicker(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    calDuration := func(now time.Time, duration time.Duration) time.Duration {
        return now.Round(duration).Add(duration).Sub(now)
    }
    go func(){
        t := time.NewTimer(calDuration(time.Now(), time.Minute))
        for {
            now := <-t.C
            fmt.Println(now)
            t.Reset(calDuration(now, time.Minute))
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()
}
```

Another approach is to use `time.Ticker` from the standard library and issue an appropriate sleep before starting the ticker so that it ticks on a full minute:

```
func TestTicker(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    go func(interval time.Duration) {
        // wait until next time interval
        now := time.Now()
        time.Sleep(now.Truncate(interval).Add(interval).Sub(now))
        // get time of first beat
        now = time.Now()
        // start the ticker
        t := time.NewTicker(interval)
        for {
            fmt.Println(now)
            now = <-t.C
        }
        wg.Done()
    }(time.Minute)
}
```

Comment: Otherwise, I thought I shouldn't use the time the timer fires to cal duration for the next full time. As I thought there may be a bit time cost between the timer fires and the calculation?

Comment: Thank you. I'm running it on my MacOS. I use `Duration.Truncate` to calculate the time to wait for the next full time. We can simply see that the time calculated out should be maybe a bit longer than the time it really needs to reach the full time. But it finally came out that I tick before the full time. It's really strange. And I have no idea for that. And I'm trying to find out what happens to my code. Any ideas?

Comment: If computing the time delay had any impact, it would make the ticker fire late instead of early, so your code is not at fault. It's rather an issue somewhere between Go and your OS and hardware (you may want to file an issue btw). In the mean time can you try the ticker based approach and see what happens? (the stdlib's Ticker is supposed to do the hard work for you).

Comment: Thank you Denis. I thought it really matters with the OS and I give up sticking on it. Btw. I've thought about ticker before. I'm not sure about the following two points: 1. Is it quite good to use `time.Sleep`? 2. Will ticker stick on the full time all long?